# failure in creating the client socket

Tags: android, sockets, client

I'm trying to connect two emulators in android,one is considered the server and one the client.
I use a text view and a handler to post the state of client and the server.
The problem with my client is that I can get to create the socket and usually I get an error message posted on the text view.Not only that,but when I try to press buttons on the client app I get force close and I don't know why cause I have a different thread for client's connection:)

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

public class screen1 extends Activity {

```
private TextView clientState;
private String serverIpAddress="10.0.2.2";
public static final int ClientPort = 8080;
private boolean connected = false;
private Handler handler=new Handler();
Socket socket;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    clientState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.client_Status);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Intent i = new Intent(screen1.this, screen2.class);
       startActivity(i);
       } 
    });

   Thread cThread=new Thread(new ClientThread()); 
  cThread.start();  
  }
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr=InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText(" try to connect!");
                }
            });
            socket=new Socket(serverAddr,ClientPort);

            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Connected!");
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Error");
                    }
            });

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good at Android programming, but I see that you're entering an infinite loop in your code:

```
while(true){
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                clientState.setText("Connected!");
            }
        });
        }
```

Comment: Well,this is an usual TCP/IP connection,have to say when u try connecting to emulators is a little bit different,but yes...after I create the socket,bind it and connect to the local host I have this loop...it could be a problem,but my program gets only

Comment: here: public void run(){
                    clientState.setText(" try to connect!");
                }

Comment: In the text view which I was talking about I have "try to connect",I never get "connected" so I guess it never enters the loop.Thank u:)

Comment: can you change while to if; it is possible that since you're executing an infinite loop, you're encontering OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: I deleted the while loop,I didn't need it anyway,but still it doesn't display connect,I can figure what s wrong:-S